# how to properly make a transaction wait until another promise fulfills Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have this code that I need the second function `handleRequest` to run first. then the second fuction afterwards later

code

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const docRef = db.collection("user").doc(`${UID}`);
let result;

    function update() {
      db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(docRef).then(doc => {
          const newValue = doc.data().Funds + result;
          t.update(docRef, { Funds: newValue });
          return true;
        });
      })
        .then(success => {
          console.log("successfully updated");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    //the below function runs first and returns a value (data) that is 
    //needed by the function up top (update)

    handleRequest()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        result = parseFloat(data);
        update();  //the update function
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Problem is once I add the `Update` function in the `handleRequest` function(which is async) as in the code, The `handleRequest` fails.

```
     4:36:22.241 PM onOrderCreate Function execution took 869 ms, finished 
    with status: 'ok'
4:36:21.991 PM onOrderCreate kPlpJCGkJ6XdsJlkxgobM5gHGUd2 
  //the console.log up top of UID. There is no log of the data from the 
  //handleRequest function 
4:36:21.377 PM onOrderCreate Function execution started
```

Once I remove the `update` function the other `handleRequest` Function completes successfully. What am I missing, that adding a function inside of a `.then` function makes everything fail? 
I had also tried a workaround by initialising the `result` variable with the result of the `handleRequest` function like

```
function update() {
      db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(docRef).then(doc => {
          const newValue = doc.data().Funds + result=handleRequest()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        result = parseFloat(data);
        update();  //the update function
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

          t.update(docRef, { Funds: newValue });
          return true;
        });
      })
        .then(success => {
          console.log("successfully updated");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

This just puts a promise object in my database, Firestore. 
The `handlerequest` function is a call to Paypal to process an orderID to get the value of the order(This works well). Once this is done it logs the returned data. The returned data is the one I am trying to save to Firestore as a transaction
How should I structure this code to save to Firestore correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs are usually executed sequentially from top to bottom of the code, but not with asynchronous processing.

Recently, it has become a useful world, and asynchronous processing can be executed sequentially (in a form that looks like) by writing as follows.

on declaration of your `update` function:
`async function update() {`

call `update` function with `await` signature:
`await update()`

Do not forget to add `async` signature to your main function like:
`functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {`

You can use `functions.firestore.document(something).onCreate(async (snap, context))` instead of `http.onRequest`.
And I think `handleRequest()` is also asynchronous, you need to add `async` signature to `handleRequest()` too. And call it with `await` like below :

```
const data = await handleRequest();
const result = parseFloat(data);
await update(result);
return true;
```

Comment: I forgot to add that this is a background task specifically, `onCreate`. A document is created on the database with orderID, the background function is triggered and the orderID grabbed by cloud function and run with paypal(handleRequest function). The function then returns a value that i need to run a transaction to Firestore

Comment: This actually worked. Thank You and welcome by the way. Awesome